# How to set visibility in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new in **Kotlin**. I have a view that I need to show or hide in conditional ways.
How can I do this in Kotlin?

**In Java:**

```
public void showHide(View view){
    if (view.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
        view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

In response to this answer, I believe a Kotlin-styled way to accomplish this can also be written as:

```
fun showHide(view:View) {
    view.visibility = if (view.visibility == View.VISIBLE){
        View.INVISIBLE
    } else{
        View.VISIBLE
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it makes sense to create an extension function

Answer (score 42):

if you want to visible icon

```
 ic_back.visibility = View.VISIBLE
```

and if you want to visibility GONE so please try it :

```
ic_back.visibility = View.GONE
```

Answer (score 19):

You can do this very easily with just one line of code.

```
idTextview.isVisible = true
idTextview.isVisible = false
```

Comment: that's it, why have more code, when you can do less :L) thanks, wanted to post this, but I did not when I saw your answer.. thank you

Answer (score 10):

You could do this in an [extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extension-functions):

```
fun View.toggleVisibility() {
    if (visibility == View.VISIBLE) {
        visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    } else {
        visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
}
```

Can be used like this:

```
someView.toggleVisibility()
```

Answer (score 6):

You can convert using Android Studio: Click on the Java file you want to convert, choose Code -> Convert Java File To Kotlin File and see the magic.
The result is:

```
fun showHide(view: View) {
        if (view.visibility == View.VISIBLE) {
            view.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        } else {
            view.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
    }
```

Comment: sometimes the bibidi bobidi boo doesn't work

Answer (score 6):

A simple way in Kotlin:

```
fun toggleView(view: View) {
    view.isVisible = !view.isVisible
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use from bellow code:

```
fun View.isVisible(): Boolean {
    return visibility == View.VISIBLE
}
```

And:

```
fun View.setVisible(visible: Boolean) {
    visibility = if (visible) {
        View.VISIBLE
    } else {
        View.GONE
    }
}
```

And you can use:

```
if (text_view.isVisible()) {
    text_view.setVisible(false)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If the View is visible initially, one can use the xor operator to toggle the visibility.

```
view.visibility = view.visibility.xor(View.GONE)
```

The correct - and more readable - way however is to use the inline var `View.isVisible`:

```
view.isVisible = !isVisible


inline var View.isVisible: Boolean
    get() = visibility == View.VISIBLE
    set(value) {
        visibility = if (value) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
    }
```

### Edit May 1 2022:

Android developers have added an extension [androidx.core.view.ViewKt#isVisible](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/view/package-summary#(android.view.View).isVisible()) to toggle visibility between View.VISIBLE and View.GONE. So use that rather.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I handle view's visibility in Kotlin. These methods can be called on any subclass of `View` class. E.g. `LinearLayout`, `TextView` etc.

**VISIBLE / GONE:**

```
// @BindingAdapter("visibleOrGone")
fun View.visibleOrGone(visible: Boolean) {
    visibility = if(visible) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
}
```

**VISIBLE / INVISIBLE:**

```
// @BindingAdapter("visibleOrInvisible")
fun View.visibleOrInvisible(visible: Boolean) {
    visibility = if(visible) View.VISIBLE else View.INVISIBLE
}
```

**Databinding:**
Uncomment `@BindingAdapter` if you also want to use above methods with  databinding.

```
<FrameLayout
    app:visibleOrGone="@{viewModel.visibleView}"
    ...
    />
```

or

```
<EditText
    app:visibleOrInvisible="@{viewModel.visibleView}"
    ...
    />
```

My `ViewModel` class looks like this:

```
class LoginViewModel {
    val visibleView = ObservableBoolean()
}
```

Comment: good explaination.. So in kotlin `visible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE` doesnt work instead we have to write if else statements in one line. ?

Comment: No need of if/else, just call anyView.visibleOrGone(true/false) directly.

Answer (score 2):

- If you using **viewBinding** on Kotlin.
- **binding.yourView.visibility = View.VISIBLE**

Answer (score 1):

You can get the visibility state of a view with the command .isVisible

I´ll show you how.

```
   val menu: ConstraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.layMenu)

    if (menu.isVisible==false){
        //view is not visible
    } else {
        //view is visible
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in 2 different ways.

`I.way`

```kotlin
fun showHide(view: View) {
  if (view.visibility == View.VISIBLE) view.visibility = View.INVISIBLE else view.visibility = View.VISIBLE
}
```

`II.way`

```kotlin
fun showHide(view: View) {
   view.isVisible = view.visibility != View.VISIBLE
}
```